# Proving that $\mathrm{int}(A)=A\setminus\partial A$

Tags: general-topology

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Int}{int}$I have an exercise in my textbook:

> Decide whether or not the following statements hold for every subset $A$ of every topological space $T$. Give a proof or counterexample.
> $\Int(\overline{A})=\Int(A)$
> $\overline{A}=A\cup \partial A$
> $\Int(A)=A\setminus\partial A$
> $\partial A = A \setminus\Int(A)$

The answer in the textbook:

First check for counterexamples, with $A=\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$, noting that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R},\Int(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset, \overline{\mathbb{R}}=\Int(\mathbb{R}),\partial \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$. So in general $\Int(\overline{A})\neq \Int(A)$, $\Int(A)\neq A\setminus\partial A$, $\partial A \neq A \setminus\Int(A)$

I am not quite convinced about their answer on $\Int(A)\neq A\setminus\partial A$

What I did to prove that they are equal is the following:

$A\setminus\partial A = A\setminus\biggl(\overline{A}\setminus\Int(A)\biggr) = A\setminus\biggl(\overline{A}\cap (\Int(A)^c\biggr)=A\cap\biggl(\overline{A}\cap \Int(A)^c\biggr)^c=A\cap \biggl(\overline{A}^c\cup \Int(A)\biggr)=\biggl(A\cap \overline{A}^c\biggr)\cup \biggl(A\cap \Int(A)\biggr)=\emptyset \cup \Int(A)=\Int(A)$

Also by their example, $\Int(\mathbb{Q}=\emptyset$

We also have that $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\partial\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{R}=\emptyset$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For future reference, the sets Int($A$), Int ($T$ \ $A$), and $\partial (A)$ are pair-wise disjoint, and their union is $T$.... And $\partial(A)=\partial (T$ \ $A).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the interior of $\Bbb Q$ is indeed $\emptyset$ and equals $A \setminus \partial A = \Bbb Q \setminus \Bbb R$ so it's not a counterexample and in fact $\operatorname{Int}(A)= A\setminus \partial A$ **is** a true statement as can be seen from the definitions.

Comment: In your list of statements only the first and last are wrong. The first has $A=\Bbb Q$ as counterexample, and the last one too.

Comment: That's what I also got. Thank you for the answer